# pandas read_csv incorrectly reading number of columns with sep=None

Tags: python, csv, pandas, delimiter

I have the following single column CSV file:

```
id
1
2
3
```

When I read the csv with `pandas.read_csv('path/to/csv')` it can correctly read it.

However, requirements dictate that I must accept multiple delimiters so my existing code uses `sep=None`.

When reading the above CSV, `pandas.read_csv('path/to/csv', sep=None)` produces `ValueError: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 1`. Obviously it is incorrectly identifying a delimiter and expecting two columns.

Can anyone suggest a way around this that would allow me to continue accepting multiple delimiters but also correctly process the CSV above? Using a regex delimiter e.g. `sep=';|,'` is not acceptable due to it [causing pandas to ignore quotations.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: try: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer. You can pass dialect in to pandas.read_csv. so it would be: `pandas.read_csv('path/to/csv', dialect=dialect)`

Comment: @JamesR I think `Sniffer` is what pandas uses under the hood. In the example case above it returns `Error: Could not determine delimiter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution we could find in the end:

```
data = csv_file.decode(chardet.detect(csv_file)['encoding'])
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(StringIO(data).readline())
if dialect.delimiter.isalnum():
    dialect.delimiter = ','  
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dialect=dialect)
```

Reasoning that if the `Sniffer` cannot detect a delimiter, it is a single row CSV and setting the delimiter to `,` allows it to be read.